# Почему не рекомендуется выставлять production-кружение в коде?

Tags: node.js

Почитал о том, что выставление NODE_ENV в `production` ускоряет работу приложения по крайней мере в 3 раза. Но при этом среди множества способов установить значение, не рекомендуется делать это из кода программы посредством `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

`NODE_ENV` указывает библиотекам в какой среде выполняется приложение. Если вы будете делать `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'` в своем коде, то уже никак не сможете запустить свое приложение в `development` режиме. А это удобно для разработки, тестов и CI.

> Почитал о том, что выставление NODE_ENV в production ускоряет работу приложения по крайней мере в 3 раза

Это очень сомнительное утверждение. Типичное приложение на node 90% времени проводит в ожидании диска и/или сети. `NODE_ENV` может и ускорит `express` в три раза, но только сам `express` занимает максимум 10-20% от времени работы приложения.